# Passing value of varibale using putextra between two activities

Tags: android

I have two activities in first activity i have  string value stored in variable i am using intent and going to Second activity i wan to get values stored in variable and pass it in edittext 
can anyone help me with this

First activity---onclick with intent

```
but1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent mail = new Intent(
                        "com.ideals.ideal.MAIL1");
                mail.putExtra("Value1", "problem was asked in stackowerflow and i am waiting for a reply");
                startActivity(mail);
            }
        });
```

Second activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mail1);
    sendEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSentEmail);
    doc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etdoc);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    value1 = extras.getString("value1");
    doc.setText(value1);
    abcPref = getSharedPreferences(FILE1, 0);
    Bigboss = abcPref.getString("bigboss", "");
```

Comment: Change `String value1 = extras.getString("Value1");`

Please search well before asking. there are lots of question n Answer on SO regarding this topic

Comment: geet still i am not getting text -- "problem was asked in stackowerflow and i am waiting for a reply"--- in second activity

Comment: Where did you call `initializeVars()` inside your Second Activity?

Comment: after oncreate setcontent view

Comment: debug the code are u getting in initializeVars()? as i thought u initiate the intent in wrong way.

Comment: @Shweta Try to print your variable ` String value1` in your logcat and check whether you are getting the correct value or not.

Comment: i have updated second activity code but still no text in edittext,

Comment: Can you change the way you start the second activity `onClick`. Look at my updated answer

Comment: @GrIsHu i am not used to methods of logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intent key values are case-sensitive so always make sure the keys which you define to pass the value in intent must me same while getting the value.

In your getting value your key is `Value1` not `value1`. Write `V` capital not `v`.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
value1 = extras.getString("Value1");
```

Comment: thank very much i am getting some values, but entire string is truncated to first 20 letters only

Comment: @Shweta What do mean by truncated ?

Comment: It must be because of the long text. It must be showing but because of the edittext can not show whole string. To see the whole text add the property `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` in your xml layout file. @Shweta

Comment: thanks Grlshu, i have also noted that i put max length as 20 letters in xml file sorry for mistake

Comment: grlshu could you please voteup my question so that i get points

Comment: Well, Your question contains a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. That is why you are getting the downvote.

Comment: :-( thnaks i m not genious... :-(

Comment: @grlshu can you please reply to one of my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20115791/multiple-spinner-caclulation-results-are-not-accurate

Answer (score 1):

Update your `onClick` code as follows (the way you are creating the intent is not the best way):

```
but1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent mail = new Intent(this, MAIL1.class);
        mail.putExtra("Value1", "problem was asked in stackowerflow and i am waiting for a reply");
        startActivity(mail);
    }
});
```

You should use the same key that you used in `putExtra`:

```
String value1 = extras.getString("Value1");
doc.setText(value1);
```

Comment: this is giving error as eclipse is saying it should be variable

Comment: what should be variable?

Comment: thank very much i am getting some values, but entire string is truncated to first 20 letters only

Comment: (this, MAIL1.class);  'this' should be a variable

Comment: I see. replace `this` with `<ActivityName>.this` eg: `FirstActivity.this`

Comment: Also post your XML where you declare `EditText` it is truncated because maybe you have fixed the height/width. Make sure you have `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` for your edittext

Answer (score 0):

Intent Extras are key-value pairs. Give a key, you get corresponding value. Take a look at following Eg:

inside First Activity:

```
 Intent mail = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);// This is the right way to call Activity inside your own Application
                mail.putExtra("Key1", "Value1");
                mail.putExtra("Key2", "Value2");
                mail.putExtra("Key3", "Value3");
                startActivity(mail);
```

Now, inside SecondActivity,

```
 String value1 =getIntent().getStringExtra("Key1");
 String value2 =getIntent().getStringExtra("Key2");
 String value3 =getIntent().getStringExtra("Key3");
```